# How to loop through 2 different arrays in one loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, iteration

I'm creating a method in my program that tells whether the if the user is at risk of covid through these question markers that has specific health risk categories (low, medium, high). The expected output should be for example if the users enters "y"(yes) in "a. fever" the answer would fall under the equivalent marker that is low (risk), if enters "n" then just continue to the next and so on then after answering everything the accumulative number of the markers (low, medium high) will determine if that person is at risk or not. (hope this clarifies the overview of the code)

I'm trying to loop through 2 different 1d arrays with the same length the result should take only 1 element through each of the arrays but I'm having a real difficulty on how to do this. Below is my code

```
    System.out.println(
            "1. Are you experiencing or did you have any of the following in the last 14 following in the last 14 days?");


    int low = 0, medium = 0, high = 0;

String[] no1SubQuestion = new String[10];
    no1SubQuestion[0] = "";
    no1SubQuestion[1] = "a. Fever";
    no1SubQuestion[2] = "b. Cough and/or Colds";
    no1SubQuestion[3] = "c. Body Pains";
    no1SubQuestion[4] = "d. Sore Throat";
    no1SubQuestion[5] = "e. Fatigue or Tiredness";
    no1SubQuestion[6] = "f. Headache";
    no1SubQuestion[7] = "g. Diarrhea";
    no1SubQuestion[8] = "h. Loss of Taste or Smell";
    no1SubQuestion[9] = "i. Difficulty of Breathing";

    int[] no1SubQuestHealthRisk = new int[10];
    no1SubQuestHealthRisk[0] = 0;
    no1SubQuestHealthRisk[1] = low;
    no1SubQuestHealthRisk[2] = medium;
    no1SubQuestHealthRisk[3] = high;
    no1SubQuestHealthRisk[4] = high;
    no1SubQuestHealthRisk[5] = high;
    no1SubQuestHealthRisk[6] = high;
    no1SubQuestHealthRisk[7] = high;
    no1SubQuestHealthRisk[8] = high;
    no1SubQuestHealthRisk[9] = high;

    for (int i = 0; i < no1SubQuestion.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < no1SubQuestHealthRisk.length; j++) {
            try {
                System.out.println(no1SubQuestion[i]);
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.printf("(Enter \"Y\" if YES, \"N\" if NO only)\n>> ");
                String answer = input.nextLine();

                if (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y") & !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                    throw new InputMismatchException("invalid input");
                }

                boolean isYes = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");

                if (!isYes) {
                    continue;
                }

                no1SubQuestHealthRisk[j] += 1;
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println("Error!!! (Please enter \"Y\" if YES, \"N\" if NO only)");
                input.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }

        if (high > 0) {
        result = "HIGH";
    } else if (medium > 0 && high == 0) {
        result = "MEDIUM";
    } else if ((low == 1 || low == 2) && (medium == 0 && high == 0)) {
        result = "LOW";
    } else {
        result = "NO";
    }
    return result;
```

The result should print one element on the no1SubQuestion array then after the user inputs, the answer should be stored to the equivalent int (low, medium, high) inside the no1SubQuestHealthRisk  array

right now with the given code the output is this
[image]

but im trying to do it like this
[image]

Comment: can you show one example? sample input and expected output?

Comment: edit your post and add the output, not in comments. add both the outputs(current and expecting)

Comment: I think you just want a single loop. You can use `i` as an index into both arrays, *if they are guaranteed to be the same length*.

Comment: yes they have both the same length

Comment: okay, one more question, what does `low, medium, high` does? all 3 of them assign `0` and you are not modifying them.

Comment: Style note: when you need to loop over two "parallel" arrays (or other collections) you're almost certainly better off with a single collection of some object that ties together those related pieces of data.

Comment: @chris Can you elaborate what you are saying pls?

Comment: For instance, if you wanted to hold information on 3 names as separate strings for first and last name, rather than have `String[] firstNames; String[] lastNames;` you'd have `Name[] names;` whre each `Name` object holds both pieces of data for a single person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question index starts with `1`, so should start with `i=1`.
You don't need 2 arrays, just one will do. 
Instead of 2nd for-loop, while-loop will do better, since it's only there to get valid input.

```
int low = 0, medium = 0, high = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < no1SubQuestion.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(no1SubQuestion[i]);
    System.out.printf("(Enter \"Y\" if YES, \"N\" if NO only)\n>> ");
    while(true) {
        try {
            String answer = input.nextLine();

            if (!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y") & !answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                throw new InputMismatchException("invalid input");
            }

            boolean isYes = answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y");
            //in the answer is no, no need to increment.
            if (!isYes) {
                break;
            }
            //increment the respective risk categories.
            if(i==1)
                low++;
            else if(i==2)
                medium++;
            else 
                high++;
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!!! (Please enter \"Y\" if YES, \"N\" if NO only)");
        }
    }
}
if (high > 0)
    result = "HIGH";
else if (medium > 0)
    result = "MEDIUM";
else if (low > 0)
    result = "LOW";
else
    result = "NO";
return result;
```